# code coverage of a file using coverage.py using a python script

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I want to get the code coverage of a python file say "Test.py". Now, when I write the script for this using coverage.py, it looks like this,

```
import coverage

cov = coverage.Coverage()
cov.start()

#pass the data

cov.stop()
cov.save()
cov.html_report()
```

now in place of pass the data, I want to pass Test.py, How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same doubt.

This gave me the result you want using pytest

```
import coverage
import pytest

cov = coverage.Coverage()
cov.start()

pytest.main(['-x', 'api/tests.py', '-vv'])

cov.stop()
cov.report()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the coverage API.  Just run your program with coverage:

```
$ coverage run Test.py
```